# Symfony twig view and objects questions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, entity

I am new at doctrine/symfony, came from a .net world. I'm still trying to link my knowledge to this world. I found a "disturbance in the force", and I need some best practice advices.

Lets suppose we have an `Item` entity with a `price` property. Doctrine makes this field private, adds `getPrice()` method. That's ok. I must load a bunch of items and display it on a html page.

When I load Item entities through repository and adds to twig I found it very uncomfortable to use them inside a twig template: must use `dot` instead of `->` and cannot refer to the private property, must use the get method:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {# item.price won't work :( #}
  {{ item.getPrice() }}
{% endfor %}
```

I wonder what is the usual practice to do it better? Instead of loading entities should I load them "associative" and give it to template? When I need all the properties should I load them with the same DQL select "SELECT i FROM \Models\Item i", but at the end instead of using the `->getResult()` use ... what?

I feel this is the point when I can solve problems, but not knowing how to solve them best :) Are there a good and big-enough tutorial symfony project / or documentation / available to learn the best practices? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

--- UPDATE ---

```
#[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
private ?int $price = null;

public function getPrice(): int
{
   return $this->price;
}
```

Comment: "*item.price won't work*" - This is not true as seen in the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#variables). Furthermore asking for best practices and/or tutorials is considered off topic on SO

Comment: Here is Best practices section from  symfony's docs:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html

Comment: “Doctrine makes this field private, adds getPrice() method” - I think you probably mean Symfony’s maker bundle. That’s just an opinionated tool, you can make the field public if you want, and you are free to change or remove the getter if you want, too, neither Symfony nor Doctrine will use it unless you explicitly tell it to do so.

Comment: Although asking for tutorials is off-topic here, [SymfonyCasts](https://symfonycasts.com/) is their official video training service and I’ve personally found it very helpful in demystifying some of what appears as “magic” in Symfony

Comment: Consider updating your question with the generated getPrice method code.  Coming from a net background I can't help but wonder if you maybe changed it to Item::GetPrice()?  That would explain why item.price does not work.

Comment: It wasn't clear for me if it is common for a senior symfony to use the entity as-is, think that the doctrine make:entity creates the entity class this way as it is the most usual way in doctrine world. Of course I could edit the entity class to make it public, it's not much OOP...  But I had other question than "best practice" - how to load the result as an associative array instead of loadin entity instances using DQL?

Comment: Thanks for the symfony best practices url - but it writes nothing about the entity classes and twig. What OOP enables and what the years of experiences suggest to do can be very different. To edit the entity class to make the properties public instead of using getters and setters... that's a way what OOP enables. But must be reasons that the make:entity wont go on this way... I wonder why?

Comment: Stackoverflow tends to frown on `best practices` sorts of questions.  Might consider posting on [Symfony Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/symfony/new/).  I know you have a variety of questions but to me the mystery here is why `{{ item.price }}` does not work.  Based on your posted code it really should.  Consider making a simple test with `$item = new Item(); $item->setPrice(42);` and then passing it to a simple template with item.price.

Comment: Yeah, {{ item.price }} works. Hm. Odd. Might my c# routin disabled me to try this. How? As it is private? or is it a trick in twig when I write {{ item.price }} it translates to item->getPrice() ?

Comment: Twig uses a [property access](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html#accessing-public-properties) component.  Basically the accessory uses reflection to first look for a public property called `price`.  If one is not found then it looks for public methods with names like `getPrice` or perhaps `isPrice`.  Bit magical but you get used to it.  You actually can make your entity properties public (I tend to do so) though there are different trade-offs involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot! From C# .NET I actually never thought I can access a private property :) Magic involved! :) Thanks alot.

Comment: To be clear item.price ultimately uses $item->getPrice() so the private property is not being accessed directly.  item.price is just a bit of twig syntax sugar.  On the other hand, when Doctrine loads an entity from the database, Doctrine does set the properties directly even if they are private.  That is why the getters/setters are optional as far as Doctrine is concerned.  Even the constructor is ignored.  PHP Reflection makes Harry Potter look like an amaturer.